# MVC: Multiple Routes for 1 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I want users to be able to access the "/Linecard" page of my ASP.Net MVC site using "/Linecard" or "/Manufacturers" as the URL... so same controller, 2 different possible URLs.

I tried adding the following:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Manufacturers",
        url: "Manufacturers/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Linecard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Adding this after the "Default" route doesn't work at all and I get a 404 error when I go to "/Manufacturers". Putting it BEFORE "Default" works, but then only "/Manufacturers"  shows up in the URL when I click menu links since it is the first match. I would like "/Linecard" to always show as the URL.

Any pointers? Is there a certain constraint I can use to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when we moved to extension-less URLs. We needed to continue to support one route with extensions.  I got around it by having my default route apply to everything except the old URL, then after that mapping one specifically for the exception

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    // if controller specified does not match 'manufacturers' (case insensitive)
    new { controller = "^((?i)(?!manufacturers).)*$" },
    new string[] { "Namespace.Of.Controllers" }
);  

routes.MapRoute(
    "Manufacturers", // Route name
    "Manufacturers/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Linecard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "Namespace.Of.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: Excellent... that did exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also set an order when mapping your routes with the defaults at the end like so

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Manufacturers",
    url: "Manufacturers/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Linecard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```